# Email Search and replace email templates(.html) Looping

Tags: php, email, templates, codeigniter, loops

I have a question regarding loops within an email template.  My current email library gets passed an array of data and a template(.html) to search and replace.  This works fine if I just need to replace any element wrapped in a square bracket `[variable]` . My library however can not deal with arrays of data(looping) and I need a more elegant solution than the **ugly** approach below

Cheers.

**Email Library**

```
<?php
    if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');


require_once('phpmailer/phpmailer.php');

 class Mailer{

    protected static $mailer;

    protected static $CI;

    public function __construct()
    {

        self::$mailer = new PHPMailer();
        self::$CI =& get_instance();
        self::$CI->load->helper('file');

    }
    /**
     *
     * @param type $data
     * @param type $template
     * @return type 
     */
    public static function prepIt($data, $template)
    {
         $callback = function ($matches) use ($data){
            return ( isset($data[$matches[1]]) ) 
               ? $data[$matches[1]] 
               : $matches[0];
        };

        return preg_replace_callback(
                '/\[(.*?)\]/', 
                $callback, 
                read_file(EMAIL_TEMPLATES . $template));
    }
    /**
     *
     * @param type $data
     * @param type $template
     * @param type $to
     * @param type $subject
     * @param type $prep
     * @return type 
     */
    public static function sendIt($data, $template='', $to, $subject, $prep=false)
    {

        self::$mailer->CharSet = 'utf-8'; 

        if(self::$CI->config->item('email_smtp') === TRUE){
            self::$mailer->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
            self::$mailer->Host= self::$CI->config->item('email_host');  
            self::$mailer->Port= self::$CI->config->item('email_port');
            self::$mailer->Username   = self::$CI->config->item('email_user');  
            self::$mailer->Password   = self::$CI->config->item('email_passw');  
            self::$mailer->SMTPKeepAlive = true;  
            self::$mailer->Mailer = "smtp"; 
            self::$mailer->IsSMTP(); 
            self::$mailer->SMTPAuth   = true;                   
            self::$mailer->SMTPDebug  = 0; 
        }

        if($prep)
        {
            self::$mailer->Body = self::prepIt($data, $template);
        }
        else
        {
            self::$mailer->Body = $data;
        }
        self::$mailer->IsHTML(true);
        self::$mailer->Subject = $subject;
        self::$mailer->AddAddress($to);
        self::$mailer->FromName = self::$CI->config->item('email_from');
        self::$mailer->From = self::$CI->config->item('email_primary');

        try{
            if(self::$mailer->Send()){
                return true;
            }else{
                 throw new phpmailerException(self::$mailer->ErrorInfo);

            }
        }catch(phpmailerException $e){
            log_message('error', $e->getMessage());
        }


    }
    return false;

 }
```

**Ugly Approach for non-defined templates**

**Note: sorry about poor formating here...**

*Instead of using a pre-made template, I have to pass a template on the fly so I can run a foreach loop with the data*

```
if ($order->update_attributes($update_order)) {
   $output ='<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type"content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/><title>Reciept</title><style type="text/css">#outlook a{padding:0;}
                                body{width:100%!important;}.ReadMsgBody{width:100%;}.ExternalClass{width:100%;}emails at full width*/body{-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;-ms-text-size-adjust:none;}
                                body{margin:0;padding:0;font:normal 14px tahoma,sans-serif;color:#515151;line-height:1.6em;}
                                img{height:auto;line-height:100%;outline:none;text-decoration:none;}
                                a img{border:none;}#backgroundTable{margin:0;padding:0;width:100%!important;}
                                p{margin-bottom:18px;line-height:1.6;color:#767676;}
                                h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6{color:black!important;line-height:100%!important;}
                                h1 a,h2 a,h3 a,h4 a,h5 a,h6 a{color:blue!important;}
                                h1 a:active,h2 a:active,h3 a:active,h4 a:active,h5 a:active,h6 a:active{color:red!important;}
                                h1 a:visited,h2 a:visited,h3 a:visited,h4 a:visited,h5 a:visited,h6 a:visited{color:purple!important;}
                                table td{border-collapse:collapse;}
                                table th{text-align:left;padding:25px;}.yshortcuts,.yshortcuts a,.yshortcuts a:link,.yshortcuts a:visited,.yshortcuts a:hover,.yshortcuts a span{color:black;text-decoration:none!important;border-bottom:none!important;background:none!important;}
                                table#product{border-spacing:0;width:100%;}
                                table#product th{padding:8px;}
                                table#product td{padding:8px;border-bottom:1px solid#b1b1b1;}</style></head><body><table width="100%" style="background:#e3e3e3;text-align:center;padding:10px;width:100%;"cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"border="0"id="backgroundTable"><tr><td><table cellpadding="0"cellspacing="0"border="0"width="650"style="text-align:left;padding:8px;background:#ffffff;border:1px solid #b1b1b1;"><thead><tr><th style="text-align:left;font-size:30px;padding:0;">Philip Kavanagh</th><th style="text-align:right;"><img src="http://localhost/crack_ie/assets/front/img/logo.png"alt=""/></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td colspan="2"><h2>Reciept</h2><p>Thank you for your recent purchase(s)from the store.<br>The Order has been proccessed by paypal successfully!</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><h3>Purchase Information</h3><p>Below you will find links to your digital downloads</p></td></tr><tr><td colspan="2"><table class="product"id="product"><thead><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>Title</td><td>Price</td><td>Download</td></tr></thead><tbody>';
      foreach ($email_data as $out) {

          $output .= '
                            <tr><td><img src="'.site_url(MEDIA . 'products/' . $out['img']).'" alt=""/></td><td>'.$out['title'].'</td><td>&euro;'.$out['price'].'</td><td><a href="'.$out['link'].'" style="padding:5px;background:#d53015;color:#fafafa;text-decoration:none;">Download</a></td></tr>
                        ';
                    }

          $output .= '
                        </tbody></table></td></tr><tr><td style="width:70%;">&nbsp;</td><td style="width:30%;text-align:right;"><table style="text-align:right;border-spacing:0;"><tbody><tr><td style="width:100%;padding:5px;">Order#</td><td style="margin-left:30px;"><strong>7782tgh5</strong></td></tr><tr><td style="width:100%;padding:5px;">Items</td><td style="margin-left:30px;">'.$email_additional['items'].'</td></tr><tr><td>Tax</td><td>&euro;0.00</td></tr><tr style="background:#d53015;color:#fafafa;width:100%;"><td>Total Amount</td><td style="font-size: 30px; padding: 8px;">&euro;'.$email_additional['total'].'</td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></tbody></table></td></tr></table></body></html>
                    ';
          if (Mailer::sendIt($output, '', $user->email, 'Purchase Confirmation: #' . $order->order_sku . '', false)) {
                        return true;
                    }
```

**Edit**: Answer Thanks to landons,

```
if ($order->update_attributes($update_order)) {

          $output = $this->load->view('orders/email', array(
              'data'   => $somedata    
          ), true);

          if (Mailer::sendIt($output, '', $user->email, 'Purchase Confirmation: #' . $order->order_sku . '', false)) {
                        return true;
                    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered simply passing data to a view (and returning the content, rather than displaying it)?